# Unable to get useState setter function to run in grandchild component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am running into a problem with the useState hook in React.

In my app, I am trying to render a modal based on a useState boolean, which is define as such:

```
const [showingResumeModal, setShowingResumeModal] = useState(false);
```

and pass this to my JobList component:

```
<JobList setShowingResumeModal={setShowingResumeModal} showingResumeModal={showingResumeModal} />
```

and then pass this along to a Job component that is mapped from an array of job objects:

```
<Job setShowingResumeModal={setShowingResumeModal} showingResumeModal={showingResumeModal} />
```

In the Job component is a button that calls setShowingResumeModal:

```
<button onClick={() => setShowingResumeModal(!setShowingResumeModal)}>Upload Resume</button>
```

When this button is clicked, in the console is the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: setShowingResumeModal is not a function

When this setter is called in either the App or JobList level, it works as expected, but I am unable to get this to work on my Job component.

I am not sure if there is a need to bind the useState setter function to each specific Job component or if it is something else entirely.

Here is the start of JobList and Job compoents:

```
const JobList = (props) => {
  const {
    jobs,
    setJobs,
    handleShowDetailsToggle,
    archiveToggler,
    showingArchive,
    setShowingArchive,
    deleteJobListing,
    setShowingCoverLetterModal,
    setShowingResumeModal,
    showingResumeModal,
    showingCoverLetterModal
  } = props;
```

and

```
const Job = (props) => {
  const {
    job,
    handleShowDetailsToggle,
    archiveToggler,
    deleteJobListing,
    setShowingCoverLetterModal,
    setShowingResumeModal,
    showingResumeModal,
    showingCoverLetterModal,
  } = props;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible working code, instead of writing some parts of code which sometimes are not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that on button click in `<Job />` you are calling the setter with the wrong argument.

Try `<button onClick={() => setShowingResumeModal(!showingResumeModal)}>Upload Resume</button>`.

Comment: That would not cause the error `Uncaught TypeError: setShowingResumeModal is not a function`

Comment: Good catch but unfortunately this did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I had passed the prop to my archived job listings, and did not also add them to my active job listings.  Ooops.